# GMSMarker custom infoWindow doesn't shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've implemented `-mapView: markerInfoWindow:` on my application and until now everything was working perfectly, but yesterday I've updated the Google Maps iOS SDK to the latest version (1.12.23211.0) and since then the info window doesn't being shown and the default info window (white bar with a title) is displayed instead.

I tried to reinstall the last version of the SDK (using Cocoa pods) but it's still not working (my custom info window isn't being shown).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

My code:

**myVC**:

```
-(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    //Creating "infoWindow"(infoWindow) and setting it with nib file called "infoWindow"
    infoWindow *infoWindow=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"infoWindow" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    //Setting "infoWindow"(infoWindow)'s storeNameLabel's text to "marker"(customMarker)'s title
    infoWindow.storeNameLabel.text=((customMarker*)marker).title;

    //Creating "fullAddress"(NSString) ands setting it to "marker"(customMarker)'s address
    NSString *fullAddress = ((customMarker*)marker).address;
    //Creating "addressArray"(NSArray) and adding it "address" without the city name (until the "," char)
    NSArray *addressArray = [fullAddress componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];

    //Setting "infoWindow"(infoWindow)'s storeAddressLabel's text to "addressArray"(NSArray) first object
    infoWindow.storeAddressLabel.text=[addressArray firstObject];

    //Returning "infoWindow"(infoWindow)
    return infoWindow;
}
-(void)createMarkerWithStore:(Store*)store
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       customMarker *marker=[[customMarker alloc] initWithPosition:store.geoPoint andTitle:store.storeName andAddress:store.address andIcon:store.category.markerIcon];
       marker.map=self.mapView;
       store.marker=marker;
   });
}
```

**customMarker**:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.storeNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    self.storeAddressLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
}
```

**customMarker**:

```
-(instancetype)initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position andTitle:(NSString*)title andAddress:(NSString*)address andIcon:(UIImage*)icon
{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        self.position=position;
        self.title=title;
        self.address=address;
        self.icon=icon;
        self.flat=YES;
        self.appearAnimation=kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot to set the delegate to the map